# permissions for fillpdf URL

Tags: routes

I'm using the FillPDF module and the FillPDF online service to render the PDFs. Everything works fine provided I'm logged in as the site admin; however, when I'm logged in as a std. user, I get an access denied when I click on the fillpdf link.

The link looks like:
/fillpdf?fid=4&entity_id=entity_name:659441

I have not created a route for this URL but I'm thinking that's what I need to do? Am I on the right track?

Thanks,
P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's working for you when you're an admin, then it's unlikely that you'll need to create a route - there's already a route working for some class of user.

Check that you've gone to the Permissions admin page and configured the module's permissions correctly; this is often overlooked after installing new modules. Then maybe check to make sure that the standard user can access entity 659441 normally; if any of the entities used in the FillPDF request are not accessible to a particular user, then it's highly likely the request will be denied.

Comment: Ah! I forgot to set the permissions. Duh! Thank you so much! Alls good now

Comment: Good to hear, don't forget to accept the answer!